# Is there a universal patch that signifies Food/Rations?

Tags: food, backpacks, signage

I have a medical bag together, which has a red cross velcro patch on the front of it. Anyone who looks at it will immediately know that the bag contains medical supplies. However, I'm making an additional bag for hiking/bugout which will hold spare rations and things that don't spoil for awhile; it's basically the size of a medical bag. I wanted to put a velcro patch on the front that conveys that the bag contains food/rations. Is there already a conventional patch that is widely used, and is easily understood by others, that conveys this? I've never been in the military, so sorry if this question comes off as uneducated. My Google Fu has returned no valid examples of what such a patch should look like.

Comment: I don't know if "signage" is a valid tag in this context, but I'll use it anyway until corrected.

Answer (score 11):

In other contexts a knife and fork icon (or fork and spoon e.g. on UK motorway service signs) is widely used, but I'm a little reluctant to propose it here, as it could equally mean cutlery, or more generally (and perhaps more plausibly) food preparation equipment.

[image: knife and fork icon]

It might be appropriate to combine with a coffee cup (hot drink) icon, and/or a raindrop/tap over a drinking glass (drinking water) if those are in the same bag (certainly I'd expect an emergency food bag to do something about drinking water requirements).

[image: Icons made by Dave Gandy from www.flaticon.com is licensed by CC 3.0 BY] [image: https://thenounproject.com/term/drinking-water/237768/]

My examples are chosen to be reasonably licensed and reasonably clear.  They're not necessarily the best for what you need (and Imgur's resizing is being unhelpful, hence the mix of sizes

Comment: In the UK we use one similar to the first knife and fork on motorway signage to show there's somewhere to eat - it's a crossed spoon and fork. Then the cup for drinks. Good shout.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen such a label convention.

It seems reasonable that just using a label with the word

> FOOD

clearly spelled out it should suffice in most circumstances.  You may need to adjust if you're in an area where other languages are spoken.

You might want to think about adding some kind of pictogram to back this up, possibly something universally known like an apple.

Comment: This answer basically starts out with what OP was already thinking (ie: "Food" would probably work in 99% of cases, but...) and then essentially re-asks the question at the end of the answer ("You might want to think about adding some kind of pictogram to back thi sup, possibly something universally known")... so this basically just restates the question.